# CMake strip symbols of header only library used in shared library

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm basically doing my first larger project with CMake. We would like to use a header only library (for string formatting) in a shared library that we're writing. I'm trying to understand the consequences of this. Basically, any client using our shared library might itself use the same header only library.

Exposing such symbols would presumably be very dangerous, since they might override the same symbols in client code that uses the same library (or links in another shared library that happens to export them). How do people typically cope with this issue?

Comment: "Exposing such symbols" - Not sure what do you mean by that. Header-only library has no global functions/variables/methods, so nothing can be exported.

Comment: There are multiple functions defined within its headers, which are obviously global (well they are in its own namespace).

Comment: A header file may define only **static inline** functions. These functions are not exported: every compilation unit defines its own instance of the function.